What's the proper location for a shower hose filter screen?
Does the mesh filter go on the shower head end of the hose or at the other side where the hose goes into the wall?

It goes in the shower head.
You want any debris being caught to be in an easily accessible location, so putting it at or in the wall isn't ideal, and there's usually no mechanism to retain it there anyway. Also, every shower head I've ever seen has the screen built into it at the threaded socket.
